# Validate implementation of ECIES

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I've created a basic implementation of ECIES (Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme) based on http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf section 5.1.

```
/// <summary>
/// Simple implementation of ECIES (Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme) based on http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf, section 5.1
/// The KDF, cipher and HMAC are fixed as ANSI-X9.63-KDF, AES-256-CBC and HMAC–SHA-256–256 respectively
/// Note this implementation does not use the optional SharedInfo1 & SharedInfo2 parameters
/// </summary>
public static class Ecies
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Based on http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf, section 5.1.3
    /// Encrypt data using ECIES (Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recipientPubKey">Public key of the recipient</param>
    /// <param name="m">, the message to be encrypted</param>
    /// <returns>(R̄, , ̄), the elliptic curve parameters, encrypted message and HMAC</returns>
    public static (byte[] rBar, byte[] em, byte[] d) Encrypt(ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey recipientPubKey, byte[] m)
    {
        var curve = recipientPubKey.ExportParameters().Curve;

        // Generate an ephemeral keypair on the correct curve
        using (var ephemeral = ECDiffieHellman.Create(curve))
        {
            // R̄ (rBar) contains the parameters to be used for encryption/decryption operations
            var ephemPublicParams = ephemeral.ExportParameters(false);
            var pointLen = ephemPublicParams.Q.X.Length;
            byte[] rBar = new byte[pointLen * 2 + 1];
            rBar[0] = 0x04;
            Buffer.BlockCopy(ephemPublicParams.Q.X, 0, rBar, 1, pointLen);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(ephemPublicParams.Q.Y, 0, rBar, 1 + pointLen, pointLen);

            // Use ANSI-X9.63-KDF to derive the encryption key, 
            var ek = ephemeral.DeriveKeyFromHash(recipientPubKey, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, null, new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 1});

            // Use ANSI-X9.63-KDF to derive the HMAC key, 
            var mk = ephemeral.DeriveKeyFromHash(recipientPubKey, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, null, new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 2});

            // The ciphertext, 
            byte[] em;

            // Use AES-256-CBC to encrypt the message
            // Note we use an empty IV - this is OK, as the key is never reused
            using (var aes = Aes.Create())
            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(ek, new byte[16]))
            {
                if (!encryptor.CanTransformMultipleBlocks)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

                em = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(m, 0, m.Length);
            }

            // Use HMAC–SHA-256–256 to compute , HMAC of the ciphertext
            byte[] d;
            using (HMAC hmac = new HMACSHA256(mk))
            {
                d = hmac.ComputeHash(em);
            }

            return (rBar, em, d);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Based on http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf, section 5.1.4
    /// Encrypt data using ECIES (Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recipient">Recipient of the message</param>
    /// <param name="rBar">R̄, elliptic curve parameters to be used for decryption</param>
    /// <param name="em">, the ciphertext to be decrypted</param>
    /// <param name="d">, HMAC of the ciphertext</param>
    /// <returns>, the decrypted message</returns>
    public static byte[] Decrypt(ECDiffieHellman recipient, byte[] rBar, byte[] em, byte[] d)
    {
        // Convert R̄ to an elliptic curve point R=(xR, yR)
        var r = new ECParameters
        {
            Curve = recipient.ExportParameters(false).Curve,
            Q =
            {
                X = rBar.Skip(1).Take(32).ToArray(),
                Y = rBar.Skip(33).Take(32).ToArray(),
            }
        };
        r.Validate();

        // , the plaintext
        byte[] m;
        using (var senderEcdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create(r))
        {
            // Use ANSI-X9.63-KDF to derive the encryption key, 
            var ek = recipient.DeriveKeyFromHash(senderEcdh.PublicKey, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, null, new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 1});

            // Use ANSI-X9.63-KDF to derive the HMAC key, 
            var mk = recipient.DeriveKeyFromHash(senderEcdh.PublicKey, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, null, new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 2});

            // Use HMAC–SHA-256–256 to verify that the HMAC matches 
            using (HMAC verify = new HMACSHA256(mk))
            {
                if (!verify.ComputeHash(em).SequenceEqual(d))
                    throw new CryptographicException("Invalid HMAC");
            }

            // Use AES-256-CBC to decrypt the message
            using (var aes = Aes.Create())
            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(ek, new byte[16]))
            {
                if (!encryptor.CanTransformMultipleBlocks)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

                m = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(em, 0, em.Length);
            }
        }

        return m;
    }
}
```

I tested it using:

```
var alice = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);
var bob = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);

var encrypted = Ecies.Encrypt(bob.PublicKey, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
var decrypted = Ecies.Decrypt(bob, encrypted.rBar, encrypted.em, encrypted.d);

var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
```

I'm able to encrypt/decrypt messages as expected. I also tried using ECC certificates, getting the ECDH object as so, and it worked as expected:

```
using (var ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey())
{
    return ECDiffieHellman.Create(ecdsa.ExportParameters(true));
}
```

So, seemingly all good! But crypto implementations are fraught with danger, and the spec I linked to was hard reading, so more eyes on it would be very welcome - does the implementation look correct?

Also, how might the API change if different KDF functions, cipher functions and HMAC functions were to be supported?

**EDIT**
Created an updated version as [a gist](https://gist.github.com/cocowalla/b39091c79b22130f111b6a6d4071820d), based on feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Naming guidelines are in: For returning named tuples use PascalCased identifiers: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33553#issuecomment-531420515
- Usage guidelines are in: Unless you're named something like GetOffsetAndLength, don't use tuples (`Tuple<T1, T2, ...>`, `ValueTuple<T1, T2, ...>` or `(T1 T1, T2 T2, ...)` as a return type. (Same link)

```
    public static byte[] Decrypt(ECDiffieHellman recipient, byte[] rBar, byte[] em, byte[] d)
    {
        // Convert R̄ to an elliptic curve point R=(xR, yR)
        var r = new ECParameters
        {
            Curve = recipient.ExportParameters(false).Curve,
            Q =
            {
                X = rBar.Skip(1).Take(32).ToArray(),
                Y = rBar.Skip(33).Take(32).ToArray(),
            }
        };
```

- You should really validate the inputs. Too short of `rBar` throws a weird exception unrelated to the parameter names. Too long of `rBar` has the trailing bytes ignored.  You also didn't check it was type 0x04 (uncompressed point).

```
if (recipient == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(recipient));
if (rBar == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rBar));
if (rBar.Length != 65)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rBar), ...);
if (em == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(em));
if (d == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(d));
```

- Also, rather than naming them from the forumlae, you should give the parameters more standard identifier names.

```
public static byte[] Decrypt(
    ECDiffieHellman recipient,
    byte[] encodedPoint,
    byte[] ciphertext,
    byte[] mac)
```

In decrypt you read the senderEcdh.PublicKey parameter twice, you should save it once as a local.  Since a) looking at the implementation shows that it returns a new object every time (and thus shouldn't have been a property, but oh, well) and b) you've created the parent object; you should also have it in a `using` (Dispose) statement.

```
using (var senderEcdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create(r))
using (var senderPublicKey = senderEcdh.PublicKey))
{
    ...
}
```

(Note: I continued using `var` here, since you did, but the only `var` that would be permitted in the BCL is `r`, since it's the only variable declaration with an enforced expression type)

- The `{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 }` and `{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02 }` arrays are being created every time in encrypt and decrypt.  They could both be `static readonly`.

> Also, how might the API change if different KDF functions

Two answers appear off the top of my head:

1) make a class structure for ECIES KDFs. Using a Span-writing one (so destination and length are the same parameter) it'd be something like `protected abstract void DeriveKey(ECDiffieHellman privateEcdh, ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey publicEcdh, Span<byte> destination)`.  This lets the SharedInfo stuff be ctor parameters / state.

2) Add a bunch of parameters.

> ... and HMAC functions

Presumably accepting a `HashAlgorithmName` value for the MAC algorithm, then using `IncrementalHash.CreateForHMAC` to later build the HMAC calculator from the identifier.

> , cipher functions [and key sizes]

There's not a strong precedent in .NET for this. `PbeEncryptionAlgorithm` exists for password-based encryption (used for `ExportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey`).  The answer is probably a custom enum... or passing in a SymmetricAlgorithm instance whose key will get updated, but KeySize, padding, and mode are respected.  Taking a SymmetricAlgorithm instance to modify isn't really common, either, though.

- Oh, and the class name is something that would get debated for a long time in API Review.  In general, initialisms, abbreviations, and acronyms are frowned upon.

---

````
public readonly struct EciesResults
{
    public byte[] EncodedEphemeralPoint { get; }
    public byte[] Tag { get; }
    public byte[] Ciphertext { get; }

    public EciesResult(byte[] encodedEphemeralPoint, byte[] tag, byte[] ciphertext)
    {
        if (encodedEphemeralPoint == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(encodedEphemeralPoint));
        if (tag == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tag));
        if (ciphertext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ciphertext));

        EncodedEphemeralPoint = encodedEphemeralPoint;
        Tag = tag;
        Ciphertext = ciphertext;
    }
}

public static class Ecies
{
    public static EciesResult Encrypt(
        ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey recipient,
        byte[] plaintext)
    {
        if (recipient == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(recipient));
        if (plaintext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(plaintext));

        ...

        return new EciesResult(rBar, d, em);
    }

    public static byte[] Decrypt(ECDiffieHellman recipient, EciesResult encryptionResult)
    {
        if (recipient == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(recipient));
        if (encryptionResult.Tag == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("EciesResult must have values", nameof(encryptionResult));

        ECParameters ecParameters = recipient.ExportParameters(false);
        int curveSize = ecParameters.G.X.Length;

        if (encryptionResult.EncodedEphemeralPoint.Length != curveSize * 2 + 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "The EciesResult encoded point length is not appropriate for the recipient curve.",
                nameof(encryptionResult));
        }

        if (encryptionResult.EncodedEphemeralPoint[0] != 0x04)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "The EciesResult encoded point is not in the correct format.",
                nameof(encryptionResult));
        }

        var r = new ECParameters
        {
            Curve = recipient.ExportParameters(false).Curve,
            Q =
            {
                X = rBar.Skip(1).Take(curveSize).ToArray(),
                Y = rBar.Skip(1 + curveSize).ToArray(),
            }
        };
        r.Validate();

        using (ECDiffieHellman senderEcdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create(r))
        using (ECDiffieHellmanPublickey sender = senderEcdh.PublicKey)
        {
            ...

            return decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(em, 0, em.Length);
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot to take in here! Regarding naming, I fully agree; I usually do use PascalCase for tuple item names, and I usually use more "helpful" variable names - I like to stick to the names given in the spec when first implementing any crypto tho, as it helps as a reference when I'm constantly going back and forth from spec to code.

Comment: The class name I used had zero thought behind it yet, I just wanted a static class to encapsulate everything for now while I played with it :) Do you think it should handle the optional "shared info" arguments from the spec too? How do you feel about APIs that take `X509Certificate2` instances? (my feeling is that will be a common use case, in which case it makes sense for usage to be as simple as possible; not sure if there is any precedent for that tho?)

Comment: @Cocowalla The questions get different answers if they're "in .NET" (part of netstandard.dll / the .NET Core shared runtime) or "on .NET" (a personal library or a NuGet package).  For in .NET: Yes, it's absolutely required to somehow deal with SharedInfo (probably the ECIES-KDF class approach). No, it can't take certs, because it belongs in S.S.C.Algorithms, a layer below certificates.  For on .NET: Your choice :smile:.

Comment: Hah, fair point :) I'll give you your feedback some more thought tomorrow, and aim to open a proposal issue in github by end of week - thanks again for your help!

Comment: Using the variable names from the standard I think seems a valid option to me, as long as you clearly reference that standard as the base.  Otherwise you'd have to create a mapping of some kind in the comments. Making a simple statement in the comments that the variable names are taken from the standard is of course recommended - if you go that route.